# Converting UTC date into GMT in Postgres and then extract the hour and min

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

what i'm trying to achieve is get get people that clocked in after 8:50 GMT my Database

this is part of my query where im taking the hour an min and converting it to an integer but what i need to do is when i taking time_slips.clock_in convert it to GMT before i take the hour/min from it. Can you do that in postgres?

```
CAST(CONCAT(
    extract(HOUR from time_slips.clock_in), 
    extract(minute from time_slips.clock_in)
) AS integer) > 850
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the timestamp to time

```
where (time_slips.clock_in at time zone 'UTC')::time > '08:50';
```